# Grouping apt packages in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, apt, alpine-linux

I was wondering (and searching all over the place, sorry if I missed an obvious one) if, in Debian, there is any equivalent flag or option to the `--virtual` of Alpine Linux when installing apt packages.

When installing dependencies/libraries on Alpine Linux, you can use `--virtual` to group and uninstall them afterwards. Very convenient to use with containers to optimise final image size not forgetting some.